# Set Progress bar visibility in button click inside the datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to set the progress bar visibilty in the button click, where both are inside the data template. I can't set the name for the progress bar and sent the visibility, since it is in a template.

Is there any method to achieve this. Following code is what I have tried.

```
<DataTemplate>
     <Grid>
          <Button Click="Image_Download" Loaded="Button_Loaded" Tag="{Binding .}" Width="80" Height="80" >
              <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                         <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                         </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
          </Button.Template>
              <Image Source="c_image.png"  Tag="{Binding .}" />
          </Button>
          <ProgressBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsIndeterminate="true" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource CustomIndeterminateProgressBar}" />
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
private void Image_Download(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null) {
        Grid grid = button.Parent as Grid;
        if (grid != null) {
            ProgressBar progressBar = grid.Children.OfType<ProgressBar>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (progressBar != null) {
                progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
    }
}
```